# Understanding how to read UID from RFID Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, rfid

I was wondering if someone could help comment on each line and go through the process of this code I found online? I seem quite confused especially with the ternary operator used. I would like to use it for my project but I don't like to use code that I do not properly understand. This code  prints out the UID of the RFID tag scanned into the serial monitor but I'm not sure about each function.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 9
 
MFRC522 rfid(SS_PIN, RST_PIN); // Instance of the class

MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key; 

// Init array that will store new NUID 
byte nuidPICC[4];

void setup() { 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin(); // Init SPI bus
  rfid.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522 

  for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    key.keyByte[i] = 0xFF;
  }
}
 
void loop() {

  // Look for new cards
  if ( ! rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
    return;

  // Verify if the NUID has been readed
  if ( ! rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
    return;

 for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      nuidPICC[i] = rfid.uid.uidByte[i];
    }
   
  printHex(rfid.uid.uidByte, rfid.uid.size);
   Serial.println();
   rfid.PICC_HaltA();

  
  rfid.PCD_StopCrypto1();
}
void printHex(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize) { //Loops as big as UID size
  for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
    Serial.print(buffer[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "); //Ternary returns 0 if < 0x10
    Serial.print(buffer[i], HEX);
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a well-written [document](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid/blob/master/doc/rfidmifare.pdf) at [MFRC522 library github](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid). Also tried the examples available in the library, which is well-commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vast majority of what's going on here is happening inside the `MFRC522` class, which we can't see because it's included from some header file.  For an explanation of that you should probably go to the documentation of wherever you got `MFRC522.h`

However you specifically asked about the ternary, seen here:

```
void printHex(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize) { //Loops as big as UID size
  for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
    Serial.print(buffer[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "); //Ternary returns 0 if < 0x10
    Serial.print(buffer[i], HEX);
  }
}
```

Here we're looping through an array of bytes and printing them out in hexadecimal.

Presumably `Serial.print(n, HEX)` prints a number in hexadecimal.  The problem with this, apparently, is that we want our output to look like, say,

```
FF 03 FF FF 00
```

whereas if we just printed out each byte in hexadecimal we'd get

```
FF 3 FF FF 0
```

So the code here is working around this by checking if the number is only going to be one digit long (that is, less than 0x10), and, if so, printing out a zero before it prints out the number:

```
    Serial.print(buffer[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "); //Ternary returns 0 if < 0x10
```